# what is this connector type (F200 realsense device)

Tags: connector, intel

I am looking for the type of connector this is.  I believe it to be a Micro IDT (molex) type connector or a version of the FPC type connection.  This is the one for the R200 or F200 intel realsense camera.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVNjP.jpg)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like some LVDS connector. However, I tried to understand what the ruler indicates, couldn't figure it out. Call me dense, but my mind doesn't compute imperial system. What is the pitch, in mm? 0.4? 0.5?

Comment: Yea that is an Architectural/Engineering ruler, that means that it is scaled at 1/4"=1" So the connector is around 1/4" in width.  I unfortunately am not where i have a ruler or better way to measure.

Comment: Also the Micro-IDT is basically a micro LVDS connector, so I agree it is a form of an LVDS but not sure exactly.  The pitch is .3 or .2. Most cables out there are .4 or .5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this manual for the R200, which shows they are IPEX connectors and thus are similar to the F200

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/612/realsense-camera-r200-product-datasheet-994594.pdf

See page 39,40.

Comment: Now the question is where can someone buy an cable assembly?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt pitch could be as small as 0.2 / 0.3mm.

Here is what I get, correct me if I'm wrong: the width between leftmost and rightmost pins (9 inter-pin spaces) is about 7 graduations on the ruler. Each graduation is (25.4 mm / 4) / 12 ~= 0.5292 mm. So the pitch is 0.5292 mm * 7 / 9 ~= 0.4 mm.

If it's the case, it could be [I-Pex Cabline V connectors](https://www.i-pex.com/Products/detail/83). It really looks like it and it exists in 10 pin version.

[image]

Edit: My guess seems to be confirmed [here](https://communities.intel.com/thread/104272).

Comment: ok I did measure the width of the pins, it comes out to be 2.4mm /9 pins which is somewhere between .3 and .4 pitch. I would say that means it's most likely as you say .4 pitch.   Thanks for the other links, I didn't think about searching for the newer SR300 camera connection. Even though they are a different layout it would make sense they use the same family of connectors.